# How to request an already quoted URL?

Tags: python, python-requests

Earlier code gives me this url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnster. Now, I'd like to request for it, but can't figure a way to do it:

```
>>> requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnster')
<Response [400]>
>>> requests.get(urlparse.unquote('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnster'))
<Response [400]>
>>> requests.get(urlparse.unquote('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnster').decode('utf-8'))
<Response [400]>
```

The problem is that requests is trying to be overly smart about quoting and actually asks for:

```
Request URI: /wiki/M%25C3%25BCnster
Request URI: /wiki/M%25C3%25BCnster
Request URI: /wiki/M%25C3%25BCnster
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does not work with urllib nor urllib2, but gives error 403 instead...

Comment: It seems that the problem with urllib* is because it's frowned upon by Wikipedia servers, unrelated to requests problem.

Comment: @maciej see http://docs.python-requests.org it's a python module that calls itself "HTTP for Humans". It's quite nice IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in requests. It is already fixed in the `develop` branch. See: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/387.

Answer (score 2):

Simple urlparse.unquote with custom User-Agent header seems to do the job.

```
>>> s = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnster'
>>> import urllib2, urlparse
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1'}
>>> url = urlparse.unquote(s)
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> print resp.code
200
>>> data = resp.read()
>>> print 'The last outstanding palace of the German baroque period is created according to plans by Johann Conrad Schlaun.' in data
True
```

Don't decode byte string into unicode object, it causes `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)` in urlopen.

Comment: Nice. But I hoped for a solution using requests. It's a different lib than urllib, really nice, but if I can't solve this with it I'll need to revert to urllib :/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `.decode('utf-8')`:

```
requests.get(urlparse.unquote('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnster').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Nope, does not work for me. Added it to the description above.